# CoreData Fetching Results With 3 Entities and Many to Many Relationships

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a DataModel that has a Category, SubCategory, and DetailedItem entities. Category has a 1-to-many to the SubCategory. Each SubCategory has a 1-to-many relationship to DetailedItem. So a Category has a Set of subCategories and for each SubCategory it has a Set of detailedItems.

Category has a Set property of subCategories, and a Name property.
SubCategory has a Set property of detailedItems, a Name Property, and Category parent property

My question is how can I use NSFetchedResultsController to retrieve all the detailedItems from a given SubCategory in a given Category.

I'm trying something like this but I think my NSPredicate is incorrect

```
 if (__fetchedResultsController == nil) {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DetailedItem" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];

     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Category.name CONTAINS[c] 'Movies'"];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];


    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]; // probably not needed
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResults = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"AllItems"];
    fetchedResults.delegate = self;
    __fetchedResultsController = fetchedResults;

    NSError *error;
    if (![__fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching");
    }

    [sortDescriptor release];
    [fetchRequest release];
}
```

The Goal being if Category == Food and SubCategory == Meat, then i'm getting a list of all detailedItems that fall under that Category & SubCategory. If anything isn't clear I'll try to provide more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your datamodel looks like:

```
Category{
  name:string
  subCategories<-->>SubCategory.category
}

SubCategory{
  name:string
  category<<-->Category.subCategories
  detailedItems<-->>DetailItem.subCategory
}

DetailedItem{
  name:string
  subCategory<<-->SubCategory.detailedItems
}
```

... and you want a table of `DetailedItem` objects, you set the fetch entity to `DetailedItem` and then you have all your keypaths begin from the `DetailItem` entity.

If you just have the names of the `Category` and `SubCategory` objects then you could connstruct a predicate like:

```
 NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subCategory.name==%@ AND subCategory.category.name==%@", subCatName,catName];
```

Note that if you have duplicate name values in either entity's objects, you will get all matching objects.

If you have the actual `Category` and `SubCategory` objects in hand you can do a faster test with:

```
 NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subCategory==%@ AND subCategory.category==%@", aSubCatObj,aCatObj];
```